# ionic 2 input has the form input area being hidden

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I have implemented a login page but the forms dont display the input area (lines)

This is what i have

```
            <ion-list>

              <ion-item>
                <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>

              <ion-item>
                <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>

            </ion-list>
            <ion-list>
```

The above generates

[image]

I was lookingb forward to have

[image]

As you can see the input fields arent visible on the first image, What else do i need to add

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you have included the .css files and referenced it in the index.html

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Ionic 2
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content >
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bmR4P1yptd2HL9YC5lTn?p=preview)**

Comment: I see where am going wrong ive included it inside the card thats why it looses that outline. Do you have an idea on how to have the form inside the cards and still retain the form outlinmes

Comment: can you create a plunker for the same and post below